# Dozer Set to List mapping only common fields

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

Dozer mapping:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>com.foo.common.data.transfer.objects.WidgetDTO</class-a>
    <class-b>com.foo.dashboard.pojo.Widget</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>id</a>
        <b>widgetId</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>name</a>
        <b>name</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>widgetAttributeSet</a>
        <b>attributesList</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

When Dozer converts my DTO to my POJO it copies every field in my DTO to my POJO. My POJO only has two fields (name and value). Is there a way to prevent Dozer from copying fields that do not exist in my POJO? What I mean by copying every field from my DTO to POJO is when I debug my code it shows the converted list of attributes as

Attribute POJO in List Fields:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private UUID id;
private String name;
private String value;
private WidgetDTO fkWidgetId;
```

The returned list that Dozer returns should only have these fields in an Attribute POJO element:

```
private String name;
private String value;
```

WidgetAttribute DTO Fields:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private UUID id;
private String name;
private String value;
private WidgetDTO fkWidgetId;
```

Attribute POJO Fields:

```
private String name;
private String value;
```

Comment: can you elaborate on "copying fields that do not exist"? Dozer can only copy fields that exist.

Comment: Added the information, Dozer returns me a list of attribute POJOs that contain the DTO fields. My POJOs only have two fields but in the returned list I have more fields. I think that explains my problem exactly.